# Attribute/dimension adding to the lasfile

Tags: python, las, point-cloud, pdal

*.LAS* files have different dimensions as x, y, z, etc. Suppose, I want to add another dimension with the name "n". How to do it correctly? I attempted to use the following pdal pipeline:

```
 pipeline = [
        "in.las",
        {
            "type": "filters.ferry",
            "dimensions": "=>N"
        },
        {
            "type": "filters.assign",
            "assignment": "N[:]=9"
        },
        {
            "type": "writers.las",
            "filename": "new_out.las"
        }
    ]
```

however, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an option to the writer.

```
        {
            "type": "writers.las",
            "extra_dims":"all"
            "filename": "new_out.las"
        }
```

Additionally, if you are writing LAS < 1.4, you'll need to add the`use_eb_vlr` option to the reader to tell it to consume the dimensions even though it isn't a 1.4 file.